# How to remove white background in picture?

Tags: flutter, dart

Design I want:

[image]

My current design:

[image]

How to make the letter back to normal color?

My code:

```
Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Stack(
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/front_Page_Image.png',
                                height: 746,
                                width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.64,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/images/half_circle.png',
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                                //colorBlendMode: BlendMode.srcOver,
                              )
                             
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
```

Comment: Does your second image asset have a white background? Share the images.

Comment: Use a stack, place children within the stack. Set background image then on top of that a circle with opacity and finally the text !!

Comment: could be issue with image ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Opacity with color as below for transparent white background

```
color : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)
```

For image Opacity :

```
Container(
            child: new Text(
              'Hello world',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display4
            ),
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
              image: new DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
                image: new NetworkImage(
                  'http://www.allwhitebackground.com/images/2/2582-190x190.jpg',
                ),
              ),
            ),
           ),
```

Comment: In what widget should I use it?

Comment: In Container, where you use color for giving white background

Answer (score 1):

It is required that the image you want to "remove the background" for, is transparent except for the text. Meaning what you'd like to remove the white for, is actually the Containers background. Meaning that you can use something like `Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3)` to achieve the transparency.

A complete example that will produce this image:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            children: [
              Card(
                child: Image.asset('assets/this_is_fine.jpg'),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                child: Image.asset('assets/fine_text.png'),
              )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I follow all step but I still can't remove the white background.

Comment: Is your image transparent, or does it have a white background?

Comment: My image does have white background. But when I add this image in flutter I don't not why have white background. I try use colorblendmode but still not solve.

Comment: To my knowledge, if you want a part of your image transparent, you'd be best to make it transparent before you use it in flutter.

Comment: How. Can you teach me? What software I can use?

Comment: You can of course with Flutter write a method that change the pixels of a certain color value to what you'd like.. but that feels a bit like overkill for this application. There might be packages that already do this... I haven't checked.

Comment: There are several software that can assist you with that. A quick google found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h8IfRewcYns

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't wrap them in a `Card`. The first `Container` also serves no purpose. So like

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/front_Page_Image.png',
          height: 746,
          width: constraints.maxWidth * 0.64,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: Image.asset(
              'assets/images/half_circle.png'),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: It works but still has a background white.