# Deleting light background from an image using dart image package

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to deleting light background from an image using the <kbd>image</kbd> package. Here's what I've cooked up so far.

```
import 'package:image/image.dart';

class SignatureExtractor {
  final Image image;

  SignatureExtractor({required this.image});

  Future<Image> extract() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < image.width; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < image.height; j++) {
        var color = image.getPixel(i, j);
        var red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
        var green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
        var blue = color & 0xff;
        var alpha = 0xff;
        if ((red + green + blue) > 30) {
          alpha = 0x00;
        }
        image.setPixelRgba(i, j, red, green, blue, alpha);
      }
    }
    return image;
  }
}
```

Will this be sufficient for the purpose? Is there anything I can do to make it more efficient?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/73387284/12098728

Comment: Why not just skip the `setPixelRgba` call if a non-background pixel is found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the alpha = 0.0 if brightness is more than some value = x. For example, here I am using lightness = 0.8 (range of 0.0 to 1.0).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as i;


class SignatureExtractor {
  final i.Image image;

  SignatureExtractor({required this.image});

  Future<i.Image> extract() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < image.width; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < image.height; j++) {
        final hsl = HSLColor.fromColor(Color(image.getPixel(i, j)));
        if (hsl.lightness > 0.8) {
          image.setPixel(i, j, hsl.withAlpha(0.0).toColor().value);
        }
      }
    }
    return image;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Sorry for the late reply. Great idea using HSLColor and lightness. Did you think about maybe keeping nearby pixels with half transparency maybe so that the image looks smooth? I tried but couldn't achieve any satisfactory results.

Comment: You could do something like gradually increasing the alpha values of neighbouring pixels so that the image could look smooth. You'll have to trial and error to find what pixel distance should be used.

Comment: If you could provide sample image, I can try it out to come up with some solution.

Comment: Ended up using a gaussian blur. Thanks.